# xslt remove namespaces from output

Tags: xml, xslt

hi heve to remove namespaces from my output
my xslt input is 
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://webservice.sbi.com" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl  xsd xsi xs " >
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy >
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@SomeAttribute">
    <SomeAttributeTransformedToElement>
      <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </SomeAttributeTransformedToElement>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`and my output xml is`

```
<FIXML xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.finacle.com/fixml getLastNTransactionsWithPagination.xsd" xmlns="http://www.finacle.com/fixml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Header>
<ResponseHeader>
<RequestMessageKey>
<RequestUUID>Req_14999064961</RequestUUID>
<ServiceRequestId>getLastNTransactionsWithPagination</ServiceRequestId>
<ServiceRequestVersion>10.2</ServiceRequestVersion>
<ChannelId>COR</ChannelId>
</RequestMessageKey>
<ResponseMessageInfo>
<BankId>MV</BankId>
<TimeZone></TimeZone>
<MessageDateTime>2017-07-14T12:02:29.187</MessageDateTime>
</ResponseMessageInfo><UBUSTransaction>
<Id/>
<Status/>
</UBUSTransaction>
<HostTransaction>
<Id/>
<Status>SUCCESS</Status>
</HostTransaction>
<HostParentTransaction>
<Id/>
<Status/>
</HostParentTransaction>
<CustomInfo/>
</ResponseHeader>
</Header>
<Body>
<getLastNTransactionsWithPaginationResponse>
<PaginatedAccountStatement>
<accountBalances>
<acid>12600262320201</acid>
<availableBalance>
<amountValue>680.1</amountValue>
<currencyCode>MVR</currencyCode>
</availableBalance>
<branchId>126</branchId>
<currencyCode>MVR</currencyCode>
<fFDBalance>
<amountValue>0.0</amountValue>
<currencyCode>MVR</currencyCode>
</fFDBalance>
<floatingBalance>
<amountValue>0.0</amountValue>
<currencyCode>MVR</currencyCode>
</floatingBalance>
<ledgerBalance>
<amountValue>680.1</amountValue>
<currencyCode>MVR</currencyCode>
</ledgerBalance>
<userDefinedBalance>
<amountValue>680.1</amountValue>
<currencyCode>MVR</currencyCode>
</userDefinedBalance>
</accountBalances>
<field125></field125>
<field126></field126>
<field127></field127>
<hasMoreData>Y</hasMoreData>
<transactionDetails>
<pstdDate>2017-06-17T16:19:43.000</pstdDate>
<transactionSummary>
<instrumentId>                </instrumentId>
<txnAmt>
<amountValue>1000.0</amountValue>
<currencyCode>MVR</currencyCode>
</txnAmt>
<txnDate>2017-06-28T00:00:00.000</txnDate>
<txnDesc>Dormancy Charges as on 30-06-2017                 </txnDesc>
<txnType>D</txnType>
</transactionSummary>
<txnBalance>
<amountValue>680.1</amountValue>
<currencyCode>MVR</currencyCode>
</txnBalance>
<txnCat>TBI</txnCat>
<txnId>    DC360</txnId>
<txnSrlNo>   1</txnSrlNo>
<valueDate>2017-06-28T00:00:00.000</valueDate>
</transactionDetails>
<transactionDetails>
<pstdDate>2016-12-26T19:52:51.000</pstdDate>
<transactionSummary>
<instrumentId>                </instrumentId>
<txnAmt>
<amountValue>1000.0</amountValue>
<currencyCode>MVR</currencyCode>
</txnAmt>
<txnDate>2016-12-26T00:00:00.000</txnDate>
<txnDesc>Dormancy Charges as on 31-12-2016                 </txnDesc>
<txnType>D</txnType>
</transactionSummary>
<txnBalance>
<amountValue>1680.1</amountValue>
<currencyCode>MVR</currencyCode>
</txnBalance>
<txnCat>TBI</txnCat>
<txnId>   DC1401</txnId>
<txnSrlNo>   1</txnSrlNo>
<valueDate>2016-12-26T00:00:00.000</valueDate>
</transactionDetails>
</PaginatedAccountStatement><getLastNTransactionsWithPagination_CustomData>
<THB>49</THB></getLastNTransactionsWithPagination_CustomData>
</getLastNTransactionsWithPaginationResponse></Body></FIXML>
```

`

and i am getting output as `

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FIXML xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.finacle.com/fixml getLastNTransactionsWithPagination.xsd" xmlns="http://www.finacle.com/fixml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Header>
<ResponseHeader>
<RequestMessageKey>
<RequestUUID>Req_14999064961</RequestUUID>
<ServiceRequestId>getLastNTransactionsWithPagination</ServiceRequestId>
<ServiceRequestVersion>10.2</ServiceRequestVersion>
<ChannelId>COR</ChannelId>
</RequestMessageKey>
<ResponseMessageInfo>
<BankId>MV</BankId>
<TimeZone />
<MessageDateTime>2017-07-14T12:02:29.187</MessageDateTime>
</ResponseMessageInfo><UBUSTransaction>
<Id />
<Status />
</UBUSTransaction>
<HostTransaction>
<Id />
<Status>SUCCESS</Status>
</HostTransaction>
<HostParentTransaction>
<Id />
<Status />
</HostParentTransaction>
<CustomInfo />
</ResponseHeader>
</Header>
<Body>
<getLastNTransactionsWithPaginationResponse>
<PaginatedAccountStatement>
<accountBalances>
<acid>12600262320201</acid>
<availableBalance>
<amountValue>680.1</amountValue>
<currencyCode>MVR</currencyCode>
</availableBalance>
<branchId>126</branchId>
<currencyCode>MVR</currencyCode>
<fFDBalance>
<amountValue>0.0</amountValue>
<currencyCode>MVR</currencyCode>
</fFDBalance>
<floatingBalance>
<amountValue>0.0</amountValue>
<currencyCode>MVR</currencyCode>
</floatingBalance>
<ledgerBalance>
<amountValue>680.1</amountValue>
<currencyCode>MVR</currencyCode>
</ledgerBalance>
<userDefinedBalance>
<amountValue>680.1</amountValue>
<currencyCode>MVR</currencyCode>
</userDefinedBalance>
</accountBalances>
<field125 />
<field126 />
<field127 />
<hasMoreData>Y</hasMoreData>
<transactionDetails>
<pstdDate>2017-06-17T16:19:43.000</pstdDate>
<transactionSummary>
<instrumentId>                </instrumentId>
<txnAmt>
<amountValue>1000.0</amountValue>
<currencyCode>MVR</currencyCode>
</txnAmt>
<txnDate>2017-06-28T00:00:00.000</txnDate>
<txnDesc>Dormancy Charges as on 30-06-2017                 </txnDesc>
<txnType>D</txnType>
</transactionSummary>
<txnBalance>
<amountValue>680.1</amountValue>
<currencyCode>MVR</currencyCode>
</txnBalance>
<txnCat>TBI</txnCat>
<txnId>    DC360</txnId>
<txnSrlNo>   1</txnSrlNo>
<valueDate>2017-06-28T00:00:00.000</valueDate>
</transactionDetails>
<transactionDetails>
<pstdDate>2016-12-26T19:52:51.000</pstdDate>
<transactionSummary>
<instrumentId>                </instrumentId>
<txnAmt>
<amountValue>1000.0</amountValue>
<currencyCode>MVR</currencyCode>
</txnAmt>
<txnDate>2016-12-26T00:00:00.000</txnDate>
<txnDesc>Dormancy Charges as on 31-12-2016                 </txnDesc>
<txnType>D</txnType>
</transactionSummary>
<txnBalance>
<amountValue>1680.1</amountValue>
<currencyCode>MVR</currencyCode>
</txnBalance>
<txnCat>TBI</txnCat>
<txnId>   DC1401</txnId>
<txnSrlNo>   1</txnSrlNo>
<valueDate>2016-12-26T00:00:00.000</valueDate>
</transactionDetails>
</PaginatedAccountStatement><getLastNTransactionsWithPagination_CustomData>
<THB>49</THB></getLastNTransactionsWithPagination_CustomData>
</getLastNTransactionsWithPaginationResponse></Body></FIXML>
```

`
 i want to remove namespaces from fixml tag i gave tried some suggested output but nothing seems to work.please help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would like to recommend you the following solution:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://webservice.sbi.com"
                    exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xsd xsi xs">
      <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
          <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:for-each>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Probably it's better to use this one in your case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://webservice.sbi.com"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xsd xsi xs">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I have attached the transform which will work in your case.